# Разделить строку с помощью js

Tags: javascript

Есть такая строка: `Пн: 10:00-19:00 Вт: 10:00-19:00 Ср: 10:00-19:00 Чт: 10:00-19:00 Пт: 10:00-19:00 Сб: 09:00-17:00 Вс: Вихідний`
Всё идёт в ряд. Мне нужно как-то вывести строку, чтобы каждый день и время были на новой строке. То есть:

```
Пн: 10:00-19.00
Вт: 10:00-19.00
```

И так далее.
Записи хранятся в БД, формат одинаковый, только время будет отличаться. Выводить записи буду на гугл карту в виде окошка к маркерам.

Подскажите идеи.

Comment: `console.log(s.replace(new RegExp("0 ", "g"), "0\n"))` Но только если у вас время оканчивается на 0, ну иначе подкорректируйте регулярное выражение.

Comment: Я добавляю время работы для почтовых отделений. А если отделение работает до 19.45, например? Как тогда? Динамически менять выражение?

Comment: `console.log(s.replace(/\d\s/g, "0\n"))`

Comment: Универсальный вариант?

Comment: Для такого формата да.

Comment: Большое спасибо)